# SVN/Tortoise Always Makes Files Readonly

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

Whenever I do a checkout/update on my SVN project using Tortoise the files all get set to read-only. Is there an option to stop this? I have 1 particular project where I need any checkouts/updates to never make files read-only.

Thanks

Comment: Are your files becoming read only because they are inheriting the permissions from a parent folder?

Comment: I dont think so if I create some files that are not readonly as soon as I check them in to SVN they become readonly

Comment: Do your files have the svn:needs-lock property set in the repository? See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.locking.html, section on Lock Communication.

Comment: I think they do, would runing this off fix the problem?

Comment: I've just checked and I dont think they do have this property, but could be wrong whats the best way to be sure?

Comment: If *newly added* files become read-only, probably needs-lock isn't the problem?

Comment: @bzim: they become readonly *after* checking them in, hence it is still most likely caused by the svn:needs-lock property

Answer (score 9):

Looks like your files has `svn:needs-lock` set. 
To check this, select *TortoiseSVN -> Properties* context menu on any locked file.
See http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-locking.html#tsvn-dug-locking-needs-lock for more information.

Also, it looks like you have *Automatic property setting*, that set `needs-lock` on all new committed files automatically.
Select *TortoiseSVN->Settings*, *General tab*, click *Edit* button to see subversion configuration file. See, if `enable-auto-props = yes` string is uncommented, and if there are some uncommented lines in `[auto-props]` section.

Or probably you have project properties set on some parent folder (e.g., trunk) as recursive. To check this, select *TortoiseSVN -> Properties* on project parent folders.

See http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html#tsvn-dug-propertypage-auto-props for more information.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem with a tool we use at work to use SVN as a Microsoft SCC provider (Provided by PushOK Software). It ran in the background and did things like this, which was extremely annoying. Once this was turned off the read-only issue never came up again.